# Can you cast Hunger of Hadar on an enemy's item and have it move with them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, targeting

[*Hunger of Hadar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunger-of-hadar) (PHB, p. 251) reads:

> A 20-foot-radius sphere of blackness and bitter cold appears, centered
>   on a point with range and lasting for the duration.

When casting it, would the wording of the spell allow my warlock to cast the spell on the enemy's weapon or a necklace that is worn, (a point I can see), and allow the spell to move with target?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No, Hunger of Hadar is centered on a fixed point

Unfortunately, *hunger of Hadar* must be centred on a specific point in space, and you can't move it afterwards. The general rules for spellcasting describe [areas of effect](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AreasofEffect):

> Every area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the spell's energy erupts. The rules for each shape specify how you position its point of origin. Typically, a point of origin is a point in space, but some spells have an area whose origin is a creature or an object.

[Hunger of Hadar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunger-of-hadar) states that:

> A 20-foot-radius sphere of blackness and bitter cold appears, centered on a point with range and lasting for the duration.

It's the general case that the point of origin of an AoE is a selected point in space, which is what *hunger of Hadar* means when the spell description describes a "point with[in] range". The spell doesn't specify anywhere that the point of origin can be moved after the spell is cast, or that the point of origin could instead be a creature or object; you have to choose a fixed point, and that's where the effect goes.

Some spells, such as [darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) and [daylight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/daylight), also have effects that originate from a specified point, but unlike *hunger of Hadar*, they explicitly specify that the point can be on an object and what happens in those circumstances:

> If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the [darkness emanates/light shines] from the object and moves with it.

Because *hunger of Hadar* doesn't have any clarification like that, there is no additional effect if the point happens to be on an object when you cast the spell; the point of origin stays where it is, regardless of what the object does afterwards. Honestly, this is somewhat awkward wording on the part of the descriptions of the other spells, which should really just state that if you want you can target an object to be the source of the effect instead a point.

Comment: Just pray you don't have an annoying player who wants to argue about what constitutes a fixed point - relation to character, vessel, planet, star, or Big Bang Origin Point... technically it's pretty arbitrary to make the planet the object of reference... :P